# NO WI-FI ON UBUNTU LTS 16

Tags: 16.04, wireless

I've just installed Ubuntu LTS 16 on my computer, I tried to install 
Mediatek MT7630E Combo Linux Driver 
but, It doesn't work... 
In the forum: 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2300107
they said that probably is the kernel....

What can I do?

Comment: Please edit your title to stop SHOUTING at us. "It doesn't work" is much too vague to help you. Please edit your question to explain exactly how you figured out that you needed that particular driver, exactly what you did, and exactly which part of those instructions failed.

Comment: Please review @user535733's comments. I'll add that it'll be useful to understand the computer brand/model so we can better understand the wifi radio devices available. I'd also recommend reviewing [this post regarding wifi device troubleshooting](https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/32664) that will provide us with some additional specific technical details.